# Conditional to autofill 2 cells if I put an X in one of the other cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements

I have to select either between 3 options located in 3 cells. The one that I choos will have an "X", and the other 2  cells will have "NA", as shown in the figure

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFKqq.png)

I want to know if there is any conditional to autofill 2 cells with "NA" once I fill 1 of the 3 cells with "X".

I have tried with conditional but I didn't find a way to make each one dependent of the others.

Comment: `I have tried with conditional` I don't know what this means. Would you please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You have adjacent cells in three Columns and when you enter "X" in one cell on a given row, you want "N/A" to be automatically entered in the other cells on the same row.

A formula *may* be a possibility, but it would be difference for each column, and would have to be copied down to each row. It would be inefficient.

An `onEdit` script will text for the cell address (row and column) and value entered, and the insert the appropriate value into the other cells.

- Use this script.
- create an installable `onEdit` trigger for it.

---

```
function selectX(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  var editedValue = e.value
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet()
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Edited Value:"+editedValue+", Sheet:"+editedSheet+", Sheet Name = "+editedSheet.getName()+", Row:"+editedRow+", Column:"+editedCol)
  // check that edited cell was in Column D, E or F 
  // and in row 8 or higher
  // and = "X" or "x"
  if((editedCol === 4 || editedCol === 5 || editedCol === 6) && editedRow >= 5 && editedValue.toLowerCase() === "x" ){
    // if col4, then 5&6 = "N/A"
    if (editedCol === 4){editedSheet.getRange(editedRow,+editedCol+1,1,2).setValues([["N/A","N/A"]])}
    // if col6, then 4&5 = "N/A"
    if (editedCol === 6){editedSheet.getRange(editedRow,+editedCol-2,1,2).setValues([["N/A","N/A"]])}
    // if col5, then Col4 and Col6 = N/A
    if (editedCol === 5){editedSheet.getRange(editedRow,+editedCol-1,1,1).setValue([["N/A"]]);editedSheet.getRange(editedRow,editedCol+1,1,1).setValue([["N/A"]])}
  }
}
```